# with statement to compare string

Tags: string, loops, while-loop, compare, infinite

I'm trying to evaluate user input, but the while statement seems to go into an infinite loop without asking for input.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class StringMethodsTwo {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String sFullName = " ";
        String prompt = "Please enter your full name:";
        while(sFullName.startsWith(" "));
        {
            sFullName = getInput(prompt);
            if(sFullName.length() < 2)
            {
                prompt = "Please enter your full name, \"<first> <middle> <last>\":";
            }
        }
    }

    public static String getInput(String prompt)
    {
        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, prompt);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question? What do you have a problem with?

Comment: How would I avoid the infinite loop. The program never asks for input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the loop

```
while(sFullName.startsWith(" ")); // while(true);
{
```

Delete the ";"

Answer (score 0):

Lose the semicolon at the end of your "while" line.